# Issues with Django in virtual enviroment

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a python application that I installed in WSL ubuntu and I an trying to link my VSCode ( from windows to it). I am having some trouble accomplishing that thou and I hope I can be assisted.

**SITUATION**

In running a script I need ( in VSCode terminal)  I get the following error.
`ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`
(Please note I am in a virtual enviroment).

So then I return to Ubuntu and I run `python3 -m django --version` which returns `3.2.8`.

I go back to VSCode virtual environment and run the same script that shows me  `/mnt/h/Documents/Projects/React/Myplace/venv/bin/python: No module named django`

So I think ok maybe I can install it and I run `sudo pip install Django==3.2.8` which returns

`Requirement already satisfied: Django==3.2.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (3.2.8) Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from Django==3.2.8) (0.4.2) Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from Django==3.2.8) (3.4.1) Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from Django==3.2.8) (2021.3)`

Given this, I am currently unsure how to proceed. I think I should also mentioned I created my virtual enviroment using
`sudo pip3 install virtualenv`

`virtualenv venv`

`source venv/bin/activate`

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Regards

UPDATE

[Django not installing in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960805/django-not-installing-in-virtualenv)
I followed this question advice and did the django install in the bin of the virtual enviroment. but it just keeps telling me packages are missing.

Comment: I had this problem too
The solution is to delete your virtualenv and create a new one. it's work for me.

Comment: @yousof You were installing on windows? What command you used to install your Virtual Enviroment?

Comment: Just delete venv folder and create a new one by ``` virtualenv venv``` command.

Comment: see here : it will help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55434760/3904109

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it. The problem is that your packages are not installed in your virtual environment path. Take a look at this message:

`Requirement already satisfied: Django==3.2.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (3.2.8)`

As you can see, `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` is not `/mnt/h/Documents/Projects/React/Myplace/venv/bin/python/dist-packages`

To solve the problem, you need to:

1. Create a venv (you did this already)
2. Activate your venv: `source <the name of your venv>/bin/activate` (you did this too)
3. Install your dependencies: `pip install -r <requirements file path>` or `pip install <packages names>`

Make sure your packages are installed in `/mnt/h/Documents/Projects/React/Myplace/venv/bin/python/dist-packages` by reading the output of the installing command. After confirming that, you should be able to run your code.

Comment: But that's the problem, when I run step 3( Inside the Virtual enviroment) it doesnt try to install it inside of `/venv/bin/python/dist-packages/` it says it is found in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` .  Can I somehow alter the install path?

Comment: That's weird. To remove VSCode from the equation, try to run those commands using cmd, powershell or the wsl shell.

Comment: Same thing, I deleted the virtual envi, went in the WSL shell,  but once im in a venv, it doesnt know anything about Django

Comment: Make sure you're using the `pip` that's inside your `venv`. Check `pip --version`. It should tell you if `pip` is running from inside your `venv` or from your system.

Comment: pip 21.2.4 from /mnt/h/Documents/Projects/React/Myplace/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Comment: If I do ` sudo venv/bin/python -m pip install django` it installs, but then it says other things are missing. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphene_django'`

Comment: That's the right one, when you run `pip install` it should install the packages inside the right directory according to the [docs](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#activating-a-virtual-environment) without using `sudo`.

Comment: Have you tried creating the venv directly on windows instead of using wsl?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237991/discussion-between-niana-and-pazitos10).